# Replacing line content in Notepad++ file

Tags: notepad++

I having a bunch of lines with following format in a Notepad++ file:

Current Format:

```
Line 53: 2017-05-26 02:26:10,362 Executing SQL query [ Select * from T1 ]
Line 54: 2017-05-26 02:27:40,365 Executing SQL query [ Select * from T2 ]
Line 53: 2017-05-26 02:27:40,862 Executing SQL query [ Select * from T3 ]
Line 54: 2017-05-26 02:28:20,367 Executing SQL query [ Select * from T4 ]
```

The following is the expected result after replace is as follows:

```
2017-05-26 02:26:10,362     Select * from T1
2017-05-26 02:27:40,365     Select * from T2
2017-05-26 02:27:40,862     Select * from T3
2017-05-26 02:28:20,367     Select * from T4
```

How to achieve it in Notepad++?

Answer (score 1):

Place the mouse pointer before the Line word then press shift+alt and click after the two point of the last row and delete, same process for the other block

Comment: I tried. But, it is deleting all the selected contents.

Comment: you have to delete this part of text ( Line 53: , Executing SQL query [,  ]), right?

Comment: Yes. But, it also deletes (Select * from T1) too.

Comment: Got it.  We need to be very careful on doing this. When the format is inconsistent, it may leads to error. Anyhow, thanks Andrea for your idea :-)

Comment: When you select text, you select all or only this part **Line 53:**?

Comment: I selected all the lines and deleted.

Answer (score 1):

I would use REGULAR EXPRESSION in NOTEPAD++, maybe something like this:

FIND:

```
^.{9}(.{24}).{22}(.{16}).{2}
```

REPLACE WITH:

```
\1\2
```

gives

```
2017-05-26 02:26:10,362 Select * from T1
2017-05-26 02:27:40,365 Select * from T2
2017-05-26 02:27:40,862 Select * from T3
2017-05-26 02:28:20,367 Select * from T4
```